# How to Validate Comma Seprated Values in Admin Configuration

Tags: magento2, javascript, system.xml, regex

I want to Add Validation of Comma Separated Values in Admin Configurations

I Know How to Add Custom Validation Using Js is just need the Regex (Regular Expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento2 manage the js validation using  Css class.

Magento uses `mage/validation`, `validation.js` file  and located in `lib/web/mage` directory of Magento2.

Then create **`requirejs-config.js`** at `app/code/Vendor_Module/view/adminhtml/`

**add Below code:**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add the **Js validation** class using the **mixin**
at `app/code/Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/validation-mixin.js`

**Add  below code:**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-custom-regs-checker',
            function (value) {
        var regex;
        regex = (?i)\.(jpg|png|gif)$;
                if ($.mage.isEmpty(v) || !regex.test(v)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
    }
});
```

image vakidation taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif

After that `system.xml` of add this new class  using validate tag:

```
<field ...>
    ......
    <validate>validate-custom-regs-checker</validate>
</field>
```

Comment: Sir i need a regular expression to validate value `'jpeg','jpg','svg'` how i can do this?